# Snapmirror lag issues

Tags: netapp

I'm new to Netapp and learning this data storage technology for the past 6 months now.
I need help with some snapmirror lag time issues.

> dest_filer> snapmirror status Vol1_dr Snapmirror is on. Source
>   Destination           State          Lag        Status src_filer:vol1 
>   dest_filer:vol1_dr    Snapmirrored   180:51:31  Idle

I have deliberately changed the name of the filers and volumes.

suggest steps to recify this lag time.

Answer (score 0):

The *snapmirror* logs may reveal more information.

*E.g.* check on the *Filer* for files named `/etc/log/snapmirror[.n]` (older log files have the *.n* extension e.g. *.0, .1*, etc.)

Logging is **enabled** by default.

*Snapmirroring* is normally configured and managed from the target system.

The *snapmirror* status command supports a `-l` flag which gives more detailed (long) status information.

Comment: Nice editing. Good to know that my answer can be considered "somewhat helpful".